# What? No module named scrapy_splash? But I installed it

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

Yes - another newbie question from a pure amateur here ... I'm in way over my head - but how else could I learn this stuff quickly?

I'm trying to set up a spider for my work. I've got a brand new, self-hosted, Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS install running on a virtual server. I've got Scrapy (v 1.5.1) up and running - shell working and everything. Docker installed too. Python 3.5.2 installed. Pip installed. Splash (v 3.2) installed and it appears to be working.

I do encounter some problems installing scrapy-splash: [scrapy-splash install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUEex.jpg)

And even though my Splash seems to be up and running ...
[splash running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LiN0.jpg)

... there are absolutely no way that my scrapy-spider will talk to it --> 
[failed spider crawl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNTP5.jpg)

I've googled, I've stackoverflowed, I've pulled hairs, I've cursed (yeah - believe it or not) - but I'm at a loss ...

Any advise in any direction will be much appreciated! Best regards from Norway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have `$HOME/.local/bin` in your `$PATH` environment variable when using the `--user` flag with `pip`. One way of doing this is appending

`export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH`

to your `$HOME/bash_profile` file.

Comment: Thanks a million, Ola. That's obviously the correct answer!